# Ubuntu 19.10 : Invisible icons on my desktop launchers

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, 19.10

**Hello world !**

So, I just installed **Ubuntu** (version 19.10) and I've been trying to make desktop shortcuts.

The launcher is indeed working but there is no icon on it.

I've tried to put the icon on the `.desktop` file *(1)*. I've tried to link the icon image on the `Permissions` panel *(2)*. None of those seems to be working.

(1)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Discord
Comment=Text & voice chat online
Exec=/snap/bin/discord
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/home/rymfire/.apps/.icons/ic_discord.png
NoDisplay=false
```

(2)

[image]

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Is there an icon named ic_discord.png in this location `/home/rymfire/.apps/.icons/ic_discord.png` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working with my custom Icon also.

[image]

***Workaround***

change the Icon path like below:

```
Icon=/snap/discord/109/usr/share/discord/discord.png
```

that is the Original path of the Icon.

My .desktop file contents:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Discord
Comment=Text & voice chat online
Exec=/snap/bin/discord
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Icon=/snap/discord/109/usr/share/discord/discord.png
NoDisplay=false
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks ! It's working !
Weird that it is working only with absolute paths, though.